# Understanding how the switch statement works in JS - am i missing something?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

My understanding of the switch statement in general is that, we have what we term as a 'switch value' and each 'case' in a switch statement indicates what code we run if we find a match with that switch value.

However, observe the code below and explain to me why its invalid/incorrect logic wrt using switch statement:

```
function getScore() {
    var score = prompt("Enter student score: ");
    var score = parseInt(score);
    showGrade(score);
}

function showGrade(score) {
    var grade_bands = ["1st Class", "2nd Class", "3rd Class", "Pass", "Referal", "Fail/Re-Take"];
    switch (score) {
    case score >= 70:
            console.log("Your grade band is " + grade_bands[0]);
            break;
        case score >= 60:
            console.log("Your grade band is " + grade_bands[1]);
            break;
        case score >= 50:
            console.log("Your grade band is " + grade_bands[2]);
            break;
        case score >= 40:
            console.log("Your grade band is " + grade_bands[3]);
            break;
        case score >= 30:
            console.log("Your grade band is " + grade_bands[4]);
            break;
        case score >= 20:
            console.log("Your grade band is " + grade_bands[5]);
            break;
    }

}


getScore();
```

The above yields 'undefined' when observed in console.

However now look at the code below if you may, and explain why when we use a bool 'true' inside switch(),  the code works:

```
function getScore() {
    var score = prompt("Enter student score: ");
    var score = parseInt(score);
    showGrade(score);
}

function showGrade(score) {
    var grade_bands = ["1st Class", "2nd Class", "3rd Class", "Pass", "Referal", "Fail/Re-Take"];
    switch (true) {
    case score >= 70:
            console.log("Your grade band is " + grade_bands[0]);
            break;
        case score >= 60:
            console.log("Your grade band is " + grade_bands[1]);
            break;
        case score >= 50:
            console.log("Your grade band is " + grade_bands[2]);
            break;
        case score >= 40:
            console.log("Your grade band is " + grade_bands[3]);
            break;
        case score >= 30:
            console.log("Your grade band is " + grade_bands[4]);
            break;
        case score >= 20:
            console.log("Your grade band is " + grade_bands[5]);
            break;
    }

}


getScore();
```

Some clarification of where I am over thinking/ under thinking or simply 'not thinking might help here folks.

** UPDATE **

So here is mplungjans code modified so that it takes the value of grade and uses it as an index to output the according 'band' that student obtained. Notice my boolean logic differs to his though.  His logic gives incorrect bands as per score.  Mine below gives correct band as per score:

```
var score = prompt("Please enter your score: ");
var score = parseInt(score);
var grade = "";

if (score >= 70) grade = 5;
  else if (score >= 60) grade = 4;
  else if (score >= 50) grade = 3;
  else if (score >= 40) grade = 2;
  else if (score >= 30) grade = 1;
  else  grade = 0;
  var grade_bands = ["Fail/Re-Take","Referal","Pass","3rd Class","2nd Class","1st Class"];

console.log("You obtained a " + grade_bands[grade] + " band");
```

Comment: Why do you think the first example works? You’re switching against `score`, but none of the cases match it.

Comment: The switch statement evaluates its expression, then executes all statements that follow the matching case label. So if "true" matches (score>=70) it will console.log("Your grade band is 1st Class")

Answer (score 3):

Your switch(true) works but I call it an abuse of the switch since it will take ANY statement that return truthy or falsy

You ACTUALLY want to use a switch against specific values.

You CAN do it like this, but IFs in your case would work MUCH better

```js
const grade_bands = ["1st Class", "2nd Class", "3rd Class", "Pass", "Referal", "Fail/Re-Take"];

function showGrade(score) {
  switch (score) {
    case 10:
    case 11:
    ...
    case 20:
    console.log("Your grade band is " + grade_bands[5]);
    break;
    case 30:
    console.log("Your grade band is " + grade_bands[4]);
    break;
    ....
  }

}
```

IFs

```
  if (score <20) grade = 0
  else if (score <30) grade = 1
  else if (score <40) grade = 2
  else if (score <50) grade = 3
  else if (score <60) grade = 4
  else  grade = 5
  return  ["Fail/Re-Take","Referal","Pass","3rd Class","2nd Class","1st Class"][grade]
```

Comment: I agree, in my experience I only use "switch case" when looking for an specific value, otherwise the IF statement is the way to go

Comment: "You ACTUALLY wanted this" - this won't catch scores like 15, though. And yes, `if` is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on that mplungjan.  seeing switch(true) didn't sit well with me either. However I was looking at this example earlier:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-convert-a-string-into-integer-in-javascript

( scroll down to where it says 'switch ranges' )

notice we are testing against ranges.  I wanted to replicate the above using switch you see.

Comment: @ManojKumar My update is shorter and much more readable

Comment: I agree with that approach too Manuel.